# Legacy vs modern printer for debian how to find out?

Tags: debian, printing, scanner

I want to purchase a printer with integrated scanner (ADF is a must). I'm currently running debian 10 and not much of an expert with regards to printing and scanning on linux. After consulting the printing wiki on debian wiki it seems that these days there are two different kinds of printers: "modern vs legacy" whereas the first will not require any installation of drivers only cups is needed.

Now my question, I have special offering from my university for the following two printer

- HP OfficeJet Pro 9012 / 9016
- HP OfficeJet Pro 7740 All-in-One

How do I find out if these printers are modern or legacy ones? Does someone have experience about the compatibility of one of these two with debian/linux? Please note that I'm equally interested in getting the scanner to work properly (if not even more important) than printing. If one of these supports debian for both printing / scanning (with the ADF functionality) that would be awesome.
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good indicator of “modern” support (*i.e.* driverless) is support for AirPrint, which is the case for all the models you mention.

On the scanner side, things can be more complicated, but for HP printers you can look at [the HPLIP device support table](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index): 7740 is listed as “full” with HPLIP 3.16.10 or later, so it’s supported out-of-the-box with Debian 10 (which has HPLIP 3.18.12); the 9010 series is fully supported with HPLIP 3.19.3 or later, so it will require some manual setup on Debian 10.